# Issue with MySQL + Node.js + Jade on select data

Tags: node.js, express, pug

**Error**

> Problem: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at
>   jade_debug.unshift.lineno (eval at 
>   (C:\Users\Dev\Node_js\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:160:8),
>   :111:31) at eval (eval at
>   (C:\Users\Dev\Node_js\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:160:8),

**DB function**

```
exports.selectRows = function(){
    var objBD = BD();
    objBD.query('SELECT * FROM usr ', function(results) {
        return(results);

    });
}
```

**Route**

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('customer/index',{ customers: db.selectRows() });
};
```

**index.jade**

```
each item in customers
  tr
    td
      a(href='/customer/details/#{item.id}') #{item.id}
    td #{item.name}
    td #{item.email}
    td #{item.phone}
```

Comment: You expect us to guess what is the problem?

Comment: Problem: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at jade_debug.unshift.lineno (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\Node_js\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:160:8), <anonymous>:111:31) at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\Node_js\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:160:8),

Comment: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` Obviously some var in your code is undefined while you expect it to have values. I suppose it is `customers`, `console.dir` to see what it contains

Comment: I would advise you to run your code in debug mode with node to better understand where the problem is from. With node;js you have a debugger in WebStorm and VS. Your usr table could be empty for instance, but probably not. The debug mode would be the more helpful in this case.

Comment: console.dir display null 
but Console.log displays a list of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is that the `selectRows` method is executed asynchronously and `db.selectRows()` expression in your handler method always return `undefined` value and hence the execption (`customers` template variable is `undefined`).

You should add the following changes to your code in order to have it working correctly:

**DB function :**

```
exports.selectRows = function(callback){
    var objBD = BD();
    objBD.query('SELECT * FROM usr ', callback);
}
```

**Route:**

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    db.selectRows(function(results){
        res.render('customer/index', { customers: results });
    });
}
```

Sometimes you may have a situation (very common Node.js pattern) where your `callback` gets two parameters:

- first would be an error - it should be `undefined` if DB query was successful
- second would be DB query results data

In case of two parameters (error and results) your route should look as follows:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    db.selectRows(function(err, results){
        if (err) return res.send(500, "DB QUERY ERROR");
        res.render('customer/index', { customers: results });
    });
}
```

You can also simplify your `index.jade`

```
each item in customers
  tr
    td: a(href='/customer/details/#{item.id}')= item.id
    td= item.name
    td= item.email
    td= item.phone
```

I hope that will help.

Comment: Thank you very much but it does not work 
it shows me the same problem

Comment: Can you add `console.log(results)` just before `res.render` and tell me what you are getting in the logs? `objBD.query` may return two parameters in the callback - first an error (which will be usually `undefined` - that's good) and second would be DB result.

Comment: I just added another approach for error, results callback

Comment: same problem :  TypeError: C:\Users\Developpement\projet_Node js\views\customer\index.jade:17
    15|       th Edit
    16|       th Delete
  &gt; 17|      each item in customers
    18|       tr
    19|        td
    20|          a(href='/customer/details/#{item.id}')= item.id

Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at jade_debug.unshift.lineno (eval at &lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\Developpement\projet_Node js\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:160:8), &lt;anonymous&gt;:111:31)
    at eval (eval at &lt;anonymous&gt; (

Comment: @ Tom please can you help me to solve this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586290/how-to-create-a-dynamic-treeview-using-nodejs-angular-js-and-mysql

Comment: @rokirakan78, sure, will look at it.