# How to create a dynamic treeview using Nodejs + angular JS and MySQL

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, treeview

I try to create a TreeView from a database composed of three fields: id, name, and parent_id

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Computer",
    "parent_id": "5",
},{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Computer",
    "parent_id": "1",
}]
```

I have not been able to do create I am a beginner with javascript and angular JS 
I need your help and thank you in advance

**DB.js**

```
exports.selectCategory = function(callback){
    var objBD = BD();
    objBD.query('SELECT * FROM treeview_items', callback);
}
```

**JSON after the function SelectCategory**

[image]

**customer.js**

```
function category(req, res) {
    db.selectCategory(function(err, results){
        if (err) return res.send(500, "DB QUERY ERROR");
        var source = [];
        var items = [];

        // build hierarchical source.
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var item = results[i];
            var label = item["name"];
            var parentid = item["parent_id"];
            var id = item["id"];

            if (items[parentid]) {
                var item = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };

                if (!items[parentid].items) {
                    items[parentid].items = [];
                }

                items[parentid].items[items[parentid].items.length] = item;
                items[id] = item;

            }
            else {
                items[id] = { parentid: parentid, label: label, item: item };
                source[id] = items[id];
           }
       }
       res.json(items);
   });
}
```

**JSON after the function category**

[image]

**server.js**

```
     app.get('/api/treeview',customer.categories);
```

**my controller.js**

```
function TreeView($scope,$http){ 
    $http.get('/api/treeview').success(function(data){ 
        var Gen = function (parent, data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                if (this.label) {
                    var li = $("<li>" + this.label + "</li>");
                    li.appendTo(parent);

                    // if there are sub items, call the Gen function.
                    if (this.data && this.data.length > 0) {
                        var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
                        ul.appendTo(li);
                        buildUL(ul, this.data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
            ul.appendTo("#main");
            Gen(ul, data);
        });
    })  
}
```

**page.html**

```
      <div id="main"></div>
```

**objective :**
[image: image of tree view]

Comment: Can you clarify which bit of your current solution is not working as expected? What response (format and sample data) you are getting from server (`/api/treeview` path).

Comment: @Tom I modified the code I hope it is clear??

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm a bit late here, but during my own treeview with Angular research I stumbled upon this post. I actually don't see where you've defined the html treeview widget,

i.e. `<span id="treeview" kendo-tree-view="tree" 
         k-options="vm.treeOptions" 
         k-data-source="vm.hierarchy" />`.

Did you ever get any resolution on your side, after all ?